# Who was my uncle?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

I had an uncle, he was a Major in the Air Force. He became a well-known baseball player, and then a videogame character! Finally, he finished his life as a brilliant physicist (for real this time).
Who was my uncle?

Hint:

> One memory I have of him was when we were both at a pub called "The Crow". A local band was playing some Bowie and my uncle was talking to me about some kind of sphere, but I didn't really get it. What I recall clearly though was that he wore some bright red socks.

Comment: Well, you just take the first letter of every word, scramble them around a bit to make some silly but irrelevant sentences, and Bob's your uncle[!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle)

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed my answer again no.2

> TOM GORDON FREEMAN

Reason:

I had an uncle, he was a Major in the Air Force.

> Major TOM from the David BOWIE song.

He became a well-known baseball player,

> TOM Gordon the RED SOXX baseball player.

and then a videogame character

> GORDON Freeman the Video game character notorious for weilding a CROW bar.

Finally, he finished his life as a brilliant physicist (for real this time).

> FREEMAN Dyson, the physicist known for the Dyson SPHERE

Pattern

> All the names of the next is shared by the surname of the previous.

Comment: That's not it, and it has nothing to do with that expression

Comment: New answer Keelhaul

Comment: Now that's the correct answer ;)

Comment: I was not sure if I had to do something with the names but I guess not

Answer (score 2):

Is this a puzzle where

> the answer is a sequence of words, each one a slight perturbation of the last one?

*he was a Major in the Air Force*

> Start with the word MAJOR, or maybe another word (starting with MARI?) that's the name of a specific Air Force major.

*He became a well-known baseball player*

> I don't know baseball at all, but apparently there was a [famous player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Maris) called MARIS.

*and then a videogame character*

> I hear there's a videogame character called MARIO.

*he finished his life as a brilliant physicist (for real this time)*

> MARIE Curie, Nobel Prize winning physicist.

Then maybe your uncle's name was

> MARI, or ?SOE. (Still need some more work on the first clue.)

Comment: Nope, not a sequence of words, but indeed a sequence of something ;)